# Do I need to have separate Twitter account for my website?

Tags: twitter

Is it good to have separate twitter account for my website? or Should I use the personal account? Which one will be more effective? My website is still have small user base (1000+).

Comment: This would be a better question for [chat]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of what will be *more effective* it a question of content. You have to ask yourself what will be your followers interested in?

If the tweets will be for completely different topics (e.g., your personal life and some product) then you will definitely need two accounts.

- people following your web page will have little or no interest in your personal life
- and most likely your friends will have little interest on your web page

If both the page and your personal tweets are about the same topic then use just one account: followers will be less likely to subscribe twice to get from time to time the same tweet from two sources.

Comment: I mean whether I need a branded account or personal account when using twitter for the updates on my website. Which one will be more effective?